# Knockout.js - enable binding for scope

Tags: binding, knockout.js

I'm looking for the best way enable or disable scope (all children elements of block) by knockout.js. Ideally, it should look like this:

```
<div data-bind="enable:isEnabled()">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: val1" /><br>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: val2" />
</div>
```

This code is not working now (http://jsfiddle.net/NquQK/). How can i implement that? Maybe ready-made bindings or plugins exist for this task already?

Answer (score 2):

A simple custom binding can accomplish what you need:

KO:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.enableAll = {
    update: function(elem, valueAccessor) {
        var enabled = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(elem.getElementsByTagName('input'), function(i) {
            i.disabled = !enabled;
        });
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="enableAll: isEnabled()">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: val1" /><br>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: val2" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NquQK/2/

Comment: Do you want to disable all child inputs by having an `enable` binding in the container element?

Comment: Yes. I need visible elements but disabled

Comment: Thanks, jaux. This solution is works. But is there any way to control descendant bindings? For example skip observables with already set enable binding

Comment: After all, i decided manually to set enable bindings for observables, http://jsfiddle.net/LS3qe/1/

Comment: This answer assumes all of the controls are already on the page. If new items are added later they will not be disabled. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/NquQK/22/